# Pattern matching custom datatypes

Tags: types, sml

Let's say I have a have a `datatype` and `type` as follows:

```
datatype symbol = A | B | C | D | E | F
type card = symbol * symbol * symbol
```

And I want to write a function that will take a card and check if it has only distinct symbols:

```
fun valid_card(card)
    case card of
        ...
```

Is it possible that I can use pattern matching to check for distinctness in a given `card`?

for example `(A, A, B)` would be invalid but `(B, A, C)` would be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SML, datatypes declarations whose arguments are eqtypes are eqtypes.  So you can instead just use

```
fun valid(x1, x2, x3) = not(x1 = x2) andalso not(x1 = x3) andalso not(x2 = x3)
```